# Can not input through bash terminal

Tags: debian, bash, vps

Very often I encounter this problem in my Debian VPS. When I type characters, the terminal refuse to display them. Instead I get a beep and shows outputs like

```
(arg : 4)
(arg : 5)
(arg :-1)
```

And then, after a while the problem resolves automatically and I can resume typing. I'm wondering what can cause this problem? and how to counter it.

Thanks

Comment: Did you press Alt + numeric?

Comment: Do you mean 'Alt'+ NumLock? In that case, no. I did not do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you press Esc and then some number or "-" and some number, bash will multiply your input by the number, e. g. pressing `Meta+5 e` will put `eeeee` on your command line. Before pressing `e`, the prompt will have been replaced by `(arg: 5)`. So it's likely that your keyboard or some program is passing Esc/Meta(Alt) and numbers to your shell.